# Linux sed - Need help figuring out why pattern matching isn't working

Tags: regex, linux, string, sed, grep

The following `sed` lines work on the following string. My goal is to get the data stored inside of value into a variable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-system-site-maintenance-settings-form-token" value="0f5ae5a6e8bb84d3e18b30b7ff2a46b2" />

| sed 's/^.* value="//' \
| sed 's/ \/>//' \
| sed 's/"//'
```

But I really think the last line is a waste. I don't understand why when I try to do it on a single line as shown below it doesn't match properly.

```
| sed 's/" \/>//'
```

Just FYI after the first sed line string is in the following state

```
483deac360aa1d0ea89cedbdcc4d051e" />
```

Comment: `echo '<input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-system-site-maintenance-settings-form-token" value="0f5ae5a6e8bb84d3e18b30b7ff2a46b2" />' | sed 's/^.* value="//' | sed 's/" \/>//'` works fine here...

Comment: Works for me, are you sure you type it as it is shown here?

Comment: Definitely am, I copied this out of the shell script. I'm using BASH, and I'm not exactly a scripting master. :)

Comment: Take some attention to `"` and `'` symbols. `Echo` command can suppress it, which looks like some abrupt surprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pedantic note. There is no need in triple `sed` power, you can get what you want with `grep` and lookahead and lookbehind regular expressions.

```
$> cat ./text 
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-system-site-maintenance-settings-form-token" value="0f5ae5a6e8bb84d3e18b30b7ff2a46b2" />

$> grep -P -o "(?<=value=\")([a-f0-9]*)(?=\")" ./text 
0f5ae5a6e8bb84d3e18b30b7ff2a46b2
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my system but you can probably get away with:

```
sed -e 's?^.* value="??' -e 's?".*$??'
```

as shown in this transcript:

```
pax> echo '<input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-system-site-maintenance-settings-form-token" value="0f5ae5a6e8bb84d3e18b30b7ff2a46b2" />' | sed -e 's?^.* value="??' -e 's?".*$??'
0f5ae5a6e8bb84d3e18b30b7ff2a46b2
```

GNU `sed` can use other separator characters and this can minimise the zigzags you often find in `sed` commands, like `\/\/\/\/\/`.

In addition, you only need to invoke *one* copy of `sed` and give it multiple commands to run on each line.

The second command should be enough to strip off everything past the value, especially in more complicated ones like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="xyzzy" value="plugh" something="else" />
```

That's if you *want* to use text processing tools like `sed` to handle XML. There are more "solid" ways to do this with proper tools but I'm assuming you can keep your XML format under control to the point where `sed` can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
a='<input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-system-site-maintenance-settings-form-token" value="0f5ae5a6e8bb84d3e18b30b7ff2a46b2" />'
b=$(sed 's/.*value="\("[^"]*\).*/\1/' <<<$a)
echo $b
0f5ae5a6e8bb84d3e18b30b7ff2a46b2
```

Explanation:

- Save the input string into a variable `a`
- Assign the result of command substitution to variable `b`

  - Use a here-string to deliver the input string to sed `<<<$a`
  - Replace the entire input string with the back reference `\1` which contains everything between the double quotes of the value `value`